# Developing a generic React component to open and close arbitrary forms

Tags: reactjs

I got the following snippet to open and close forms on my page:

```
 <div>
   {this.state.editFormOpen?
   <div>
       <Link
          to=''
          onClick={()=>{this.setState({editFormOpen:false})}}>
          Close
       </Link>
       <PostForm
           onSubmit={(post)=>this.createPost(post)}
       />
   </div>:
   <Link
     to=''
     onClick={()=>{this.setState({editFormOpen:true})}}>
     Add post
  </Link>}
</div>
```

Now in order to avoid repeating myself, I want to refactore that code into a seperate `<FormHandler/>` component, such that it works for arbitrary forms, not only
`<PostForm/>`. I.e., I need to be able to pass any form component to the `<FormHandler/>`.

How can I do this in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have everything you need in order to accomplish that. Maybe just change the line where you render `PostForm` and accept `props.children` coming from your new component. With that you will be able to render any form you want inside of it.

Remember that the less business logic you keep outside of `FormHandler` the better. Each form should be aware of what to do on every field change or on submit.

For example, `this.createPost` **should not** be part of `FormHandler` in case you want to reuse it throughout your code.

```js
class FormHandler extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      formOpen: false,
    }

    this.toggleFormOpen = this.toggleFormOpen.bind(this)
  }

  toggleFormOpen() {
    this.setState({
      formOpen: !this.state.formOpen,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleFormOpen}>
          {this.state.formOpen ? 'Close' : 'Open'}
        </button>
        {this.state.formOpen && React.cloneElement(
          this.props.children,
          {
            onClose: this.toggleFormOpen
          }
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const PostForm = ({ onClose, onSubmit }) =>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Post Name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Post Title" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Date" />
    <button onClick={event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      onSubmit({ postName: '', postTitle: '', date: ''})
      onClose()
    }}>
      Submit
    </button>  
  </form>

const UserForm = ({ onClose, onSubmit }) => 
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <button onClick={event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      onSubmit({ firstName: '', lastName: '' })
      onClose()
    }}>
      Submit
    </button>  
  </form>

const App = () => 
  <div>
    <FormHandler>
     <PostForm
       onSubmit={formData => console.log('PostForm', formData)}
     />
    </FormHandler>
    <br />
    <FormHandler>
     <UserForm
       onSubmit={formData => console.log('UserForm', formData)}
     />
    </FormHandler>
  </div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Additional challenge: I want to close the inner form on submit. i.e., I need the FormHandler to subscribe to the onSubmit event of the child form and set toggleFormOpen to false. How would I get that into the code above?

Comment: You can [clone](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) `this.props.children` for example and subscribe to `onSubmit`.

Comment: @mersicarlin: Could you explain that in a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I will go about it by making a factory that returns a React Component, than render the children as props

```
const FormHandlerFactory = ({Form = PostForm}) => {
    return class FormHandler extends React.Component {
       render() {
           return (
               <div>
                   {this.state.editFormOpen?
                   <div>
                       <Link
                          to=''
                          onClick={()=>{this.setState({editFormOpen:false})}}>
                          Close
                       </Link>
                       <Form
                           onSubmit={(post)=>this.createPost(post)}
                       />
                   </div>:
                   <Link
                     to=''
                     onClick={()=>{this.setState({editFormOpen:true})}}>
                     Add post
                  </Link>}
                </div>
            )
       }
    }
}
```

You can use this factory as

```
const FormHandler = FormHandlerFactory({Form: YourCustomFormComponent});
const App = (props) => (
     <Form {...props}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a stateless component that could render any children that you passed in that component you also need to put the states in the parent component

```
const ToggleForm = ({ editFormOpen, editFormHandler, children }) => (
 <div>
   {editFormOpen?
   <div>
       <Link
          to=''
          onClick={() => editFormHandler(false)}>
          Close
       </Link>
       {children}
   </div>:
   <Link
     to=''
     onClick={() => editFormHandler(true)}>
     Add post
  </Link>}
</div>
);

class ParentCmp extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       editFormOpen: false,
     }
     this.editFormHandler = this.editFormHandler.bind(this);
     this.createPost = this.createPost.bind(this);
   }
   editFormHandler(boolValue) {
     this.setState({
       editFormOpen: boolValue
     });
   }
   render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <ToggleForm
              editFormOpen={this.state.editFormOpen}
              editFormHandler={this.state.editFormHandler}
            >
                <PostForm
                    onSubmit={(post)=>this.createPost(post)}
                />
            </ToggleForm>
        </div>
      )
   }
}
```